# Can't get scrollsToTop working on iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uistatusbar

I'm targeting iOS7 in my latest app, and tapping on the status bar doesn't seem to scroll a tableView or collectionView to the top.

I've set `self.tableView.scrollsToTop = true` and still nothing happens.

I know Apple significantly changed the status bar in iOS7, but did those changes break the `scrollsToTop` functionality?

**Update**

In response to a comment in one of the answers, I tested to ensure that my collection view was indeed the only scrollView on the screen, and it was:

```
(lldb) po [self.view recursiveDescription]
<UIView: 0x1092ddf0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x109357e0>>
   | <UICollectionView: 0x11351800; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10966080>; layer = <CALayer: 0x109623a0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x10940a70>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x10965fa0; frame = (0 564.5; 320 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10965ee0>> - (null)
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x10948f60; frame = (316.5 561; 3.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10966030>> - (null)
```

**Update #2**

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using a standard iOS7 NavigationController where the navigationBar is transparent and applies a blur to my collection/tableViews as they scroll underneath.

**Update #3**

Figured it out. Turns out I *did* have more than one scrollView on the screen. My app has a left drawer menu underneath the main part of the app, and that menu has a tableView for the options. I simply set `self.menuTable.scrollsToTop = false` and everything worked as expected throughout the rest of the app. Didn't have to implement the scrollView Delegate methods or anything.

Comment: Do you need to set something like, self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; ? But for the tableview..

Comment: Great suggestion in update #3, got that worked out just the same way. But the weird thing was that without update #3 fix it worked in iOS8 but not in iOS7.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you have more than one scroll view/table view/collection view on screen? If so, only one of them can have [`scrollsToTop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop) set to `YES`, otherwise iOS7 will not scroll any of them to the top.

You can also implement the UIScrollViewDelegate method [`scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewShouldScrollToTop%3a) and return YES if the passed in scroll view is equal to the one that you want to scroll to the top:

```
- (BOOL) scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView*) scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.myTableView) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell I only have my tableView in one particular view controller, and a collectionView on another. I set both to scrollsToTop = true, and implemented the scrollview delegate method you suggested. I threw a log statement at the top, and that method is never getting called. I tried on the simulator and the device.

Comment: Are both of those view controller's views visible simultaneously?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. these are two totally different parts of the app.

Comment: Are there any other scroll views (or scroll view subclasses, such as table view or collection view) on the screen? As apple's docs say, "On iPhone, the scroll-to-top gesture has no effect if there is more than one scroll view on-screen that has scrollsToTop set to YES."

Comment: no, my collection view is the only one. check out the update to my question, where i post the result of [self.view recursiveDescription]

Comment: ah ha - I actually had EXACTLY this problem on an app I built (slide out drawer with table view, and main view with table view). Glad it's working for you now!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38250/discussion-between-greg-and-djibouti33)

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is there's nothing different in iOS7. As long as there isn't more than one UIScrollView loaded, your tableView or collectionView will scroll to the top when the user taps the status bar. The key here is loaded; another scrollView doesn't necessarily have to be on screen to conflict with another scrollView that is.

Sliding drawers in the left/right are very popular these days, and this was the reason for my problem. I have a menu containing my navigation options, and these are all held by a UITableView. I had to make sure that I set `menuTable.scrollsToTop = false` before I could get things working in the other parts of my app.

Comment: Yes! This did it for me! :D

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day :)

Comment: This surely save my time.

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that I had a `UITextView` with `scrollsToTop` set to `YES`, so my `UITableView` wasn't responding to the gesture. In short, make check all other scrollable views.

Answer (score 4):

for others :

Remember that the scroll view you are searching can also be a UIWebView..not just UITableView.
Another important thing is that it's not only about VISIBLE scrollViews, but LOADED scrollviews.

If you don't find the scrollView, you can always
insert UITableView test table, immediately when app is starting, check if it's scroll to top,
and then load more and more views, until the test table stop scrolling to top.

Answer (score 4):

If your table cells are dynamic, remove the following:

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return YES;
}
```

Create a new function as follows:

```
- (void) disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollsToTop = NO;
        }
        [self disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:subview];
    }
}
```

Call the function above in `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
[self disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:self.view];
```

Now enable ScrollsToTop for your table view as follows:

```
[myTableView setScrollsToTop:YES];
```

Answer (score -2):

This always works for me:

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```